# Trying to write a simple drawing program for android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to figure out how to wite a simple drawing program in Android.  I saw a sample program that stored each stroke in a array, then played back the array when the screen needed to be updated. To me this did not seem to proctical.  I would like to draw in a bitmap, and the update would just draw the bitmap instad of every stroke. ( i could not figure out how to do this in android)

Any thoughts
?
Ted

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Android samples: there are a couple of moderately complicated bits, but this is from the Sensors.java api demo in the Android SDK. It demonstrates the bitmap manipulation:

```
private class GraphView extends View implements SensorEventListener
    {
        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
        private Canvas  mCanvas = new Canvas();
        private Path    mPath = new Path();
        private RectF   mRect = new RectF();
        private float   mLastValues[] = new float[3*2];
        private float   mOrientationValues[] = new float[3];
        private int     mColors[] = new int[3*2];
        private float   mLastX;
        private float   mScale[] = new float[2];
        private float   mYOffset;
        private float   mMaxX;
        private float   mSpeed = 1.0f;
        private float   mWidth;
        private float   mHeight;

        public GraphView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mColors[0] = Color.argb(192, 255, 64, 64);
            mColors[1] = Color.argb(192, 64, 128, 64);
            mColors[2] = Color.argb(192, 64, 64, 255);
            mColors[3] = Color.argb(192, 64, 255, 255);
            mColors[4] = Color.argb(192, 128, 64, 128);
            mColors[5] = Color.argb(192, 255, 255, 64);

            mPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mRect.set(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
            mPath.arcTo(mRect, 0, 180);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
            mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            mYOffset = h * 0.5f;
            mScale[0] = - (h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY * 2)));
            mScale[1] = - (h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.MAGNETIC_FIELD_EARTH_MAX)));
            mWidth = w;
            mHeight = h;
            if (mWidth < mHeight) {
                mMaxX = w;
            } else {
                mMaxX = w-50;
            }
            mLastX = mMaxX;
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mBitmap != null) {
                    final Paint paint = mPaint;
                    final Path path = mPath;
                    final int outer = 0xFFC0C0C0;
                    final int inner = 0xFFff7010;

                    if (mLastX >= mMaxX) {
                        mLastX = 0;
                        final Canvas cavas = mCanvas;
                        final float yoffset = mYOffset;
                        final float maxx = mMaxX;
                        final float oneG = SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY * mScale[0];
                        paint.setColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
                        cavas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                        cavas.drawLine(0, yoffset,      maxx, yoffset,      paint);
                        cavas.drawLine(0, yoffset+oneG, maxx, yoffset+oneG, paint);
                        cavas.drawLine(0, yoffset-oneG, maxx, yoffset-oneG, paint);
                    }
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);

                    float[] values = mOrientationValues;
                    if (mWidth < mHeight) {
                        float w0 = mWidth * 0.333333f;
                        float w  = w0 - 32;
                        float x = w0*0.5f;
                        for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
                            canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                            canvas.translate(x, w*0.5f + 4.0f);
                            canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                            paint.setColor(outer);
                            canvas.scale(w, w);
                            canvas.drawOval(mRect, paint);
                            canvas.restore();
                            canvas.scale(w-5, w-5);
                            paint.setColor(inner);
                            canvas.rotate(-values[i]);
                            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                            canvas.restore();
                            x += w0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        float h0 = mHeight * 0.333333f;
                        float h  = h0 - 32;
                        float y = h0*0.5f;
                        for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
                            canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                            canvas.translate(mWidth - (h*0.5f + 4.0f), y);
                            canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                            paint.setColor(outer);
                            canvas.scale(h, h);
                            canvas.drawOval(mRect, paint);
                            canvas.restore();
                            canvas.scale(h-5, h-5);
                            paint.setColor(inner);
                            canvas.rotate(-values[i]);
                            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                            canvas.restore();
                            y += h0;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "sensor: " + sensor + ", x: " + values[0] + ", y: " + values[1] + ", z: " + values[2]);
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mBitmap != null) {
                    final Canvas canvas = mCanvas;
                    final Paint paint = mPaint;
                    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
                        for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
                            mOrientationValues[i] = event.values[i];
                        }
                    } else {
                        float deltaX = mSpeed;
                        float newX = mLastX + deltaX;

                        int j = (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) ? 1 : 0;
                        for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
                            int k = i+j*3;
                            final float v = mYOffset + event.values[i] * mScale[j];
                            paint.setColor(mColors[k]);
                            canvas.drawLine(mLastX, mLastValues[k], newX, v, paint);
                            mLastValues[k] = v;
                        }
                        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
                            mLastX += mSpeed;
                    }
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    }
```